# java: string builder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I want to append `,` to a StringBuilder if the variable `a` is less than the  length of the Array.
I am incrementing the variable `a` everytime, and I am using the following code:

```
for(int n=0;n<fieldMap.length();n++)
{
    int a=0;
    JSONObject object = fieldMap.getJSONObject(n);              
    String type= object.getString("type");
    String name= object.getString("name");

    createTable.append(name +" ");
    createTable.append(type);
    a++;

    if(!(a==(fieldMap.length()-1))) {
        createTable.append(",");
    }                       
}
```

But it is appending `,` at the end also which I don't want. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Also its better to append without checking and strip the comma after the loop, you can improve performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `a` outside the for loop:

```
int a=0;
for(int n=0;n<fieldMap.length();n++){
```

Or just use `n` instead of `a`.

You can also simplify your logic slightly by writing the comma first:

```
 for(int n=0; n < fieldMap.length(); n++){
     JSONObject object = fieldMap.getJSONObject(n);             
     String type = object.getString("type");
     String name = object.getString("name");

     if (n != 0) {
         createTable.append(",");
     }
     createTable.append(name + " ");
     createTable.append(type);
}
```